# What is the issue with vim -u /path_to/vimrc?

Tags: vim

I share an user with other people.
Everyone has created a directory into home directory and everyone is working in his "own" directory.
I want to use my own setting when I use vim and I don't want to bother others with my preferences.

I created my .vimrc file into $HOME/my_directory

I've defined an alias `my_vim="vim -u /full_path_to_home/my_directory/.vimrc"`

When I edit a file with my_vim, I don't have the right colors.

I have the same problem when I use the command
`:source  /full_path_to_home/my_directory/.vimrc`

If I copy my .vimrc file into $HOME directory, everything is fine.

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help vimrc`

> If Vim was started with "-u filename",
>   the file "filename" is used.
>   All following initializations until 4.
>   are skipped.

So by specifying a vimrc file, its ignoring the system-wide vimrc (`/erc/vimrc/`) where syntax highlighting and other things are configured. You can work around this problem by adding the following code to the *top* of your vimrc:

```
if filereadable("/etc/vimrc")
  source /etc/vimrc
endif
```

Comment: @ajwood With the information provided, I don't see how it can't be a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry, you must have edited the answer as I was typing the comment. I thought you'd only quoted the docs. +1

Answer (score 1):

If this sort of thing comes up a lot, I would recommend changing your `$HOME` to point to the current `$HOME/my_directory` whenever you log in.

Comment: There might be a good reason he's sharing home directories, and editing `$HOME` might mess around with that reason.

Comment: I didn't mean in the .bashrc or whatever, I meant manually typing `export HOME=$HOME/my_directory` when he opens a terminal for himself.