# vimrc is not loading when I run mvim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I just switched to using vim, and am working on my vimrc. My problem is MacVim is not loading my vimrc when it opens, I have to explicitly run `:source ~/.vimrc` for my settings to be applied. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you perhaps have a `~/_vimrc` file? Mac looks for a vimrc file in both locations, but it may stop looking if it checks for and finds a `~/_vimrc` file first.

If that doesn't help, you can also workaround this by running `vim -u ~/.vimrc`. Although take note of this issue raised in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522440/what-is-the-issue-with-vim-u-path-to-vimrc/4522491).

Comment: I dont have a ~/_vimrc, I would rather not have to hack the mvim startup script for this to work but I guess I might have to.

Comment: Figured out I had a .gvimrc that I didnt see.